# Error Connecting Milvus to Milvus Cloud Database: Need Assistance

Tags: python, milvus

Everyone I am facing issue with milvus connection and getting this error:

```
"pymilvus.exception.MilvusException: <MilvusException: (code = 2, message = Fail connecting to server on "URI" . Timout)>
```

someone please help me with this.

```
def connect:
    URI = os.getenv('URI')
    TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
    connections.connect(uri = URI, token = TOKEN, secure = True)
```

Comment: You mean connect to zillzcloud failed?

Comment: Yes when I specify the right credentials inside the connect function that time I am getting the above error.

Comment: Try [this](https://docs.zilliz.com/docs/faq-cluster?_highlight=connect#how-can-i-deal-with-a-connection-timeout-error-when-i-attempt-to-connect-to-zilliz-cloud) .